# pytorch : retain_graph=True error even though i add this

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I keep getting this error
**"Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the saved intermediate results have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling .backward() or autograd.grad() the first time."**

in the beginning, it was without retain_graph=True and then I got the error so I add it to the backward but I am still getting the same error.

i read similar questions but nothing helped.
would like to get help!

```
trained_cnnfmnist_model=net

class CNNFMnist2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, trained_cnnfmnist_model):
        super(CNNFMnist2, self).__init__()
        self.trained_cnnfmnist_model = trained_cnnfmnist_model
        # now a few fully connected layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.fc2=  nn.Linear(32,16)
        self.fc3=  nn.Linear(16,10)

    def forward(self, x):
      x = self.trained_cnnfmnist_model(x)
      x = F.relu(self.fc1(x[0]))
      print(x.shape)
      # x = x.view(-1, self.num_flat_features(x))
      x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
      x = self.fc3(x)
      return x 

trainset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

testset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True)

testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False)

net2 = CNNFMnist2(trained_cnnfmnist_model).cuda()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net2.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):  

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # get the inputs
        inputs, labels = data
        
        inputs = inputs.cuda() # -- For GPU
        labels = labels.cuda() # -- For GPU

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        output = net2(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
        optimizer.step()

        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if (i+1) % 2000 == 0:    
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Comment: You'll have to put all the stacktrace here. Because it's important to know which line cause that error.

Comment: But from what I see. This error is because there is another `optimizer.step()` somewhere. Delete that.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen hey , first thank you! i do have another optimizer.step() but i used it to train the trained_cnnfmnist_model. so why should i need to delete it? first i train this model and then i train the model that get this model and have another  layers.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen so i tried what you say, i just put this model without training and then it worked , and after that i changed the optimizers names and it worked with both of them. so first thank you! really! second, i  didn't understand why it happened because i initialize it each time before the train. first time:
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9) .second:optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net2.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can only call `optimizer.step()` after these three lines.

```
        output = net2(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
```

I don't know the rest of your code so I can only guess.

But I think you didn't have `net(inputs)` before you call `optimizer.step()`.